# Synchronize DX rendering with WPF rendering

Tags: wpf, gdi+, gdi, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have WPF application in which we host a WinForms control (CEFSharp browser). Browser is drawing on DX surface. When resizing parts of the application it seems the rendering of the browser occurs more often than WPF controls and I see the issue below, where DX surface draw over WPF elements. Please advice me how avoid the effect on the image below.

Using WPF Cefsharp control is not an options because it is slow and buggy.

[image: Async drawing between GDI and WPF]

Comment: Browser uses native (win32) windows and do not perform any GDI drawings for content. More like it draw to DX surface in accelerated cases if you use normal (windowed) browser.

Comment: `Chromium` uses (Angle)[https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle] library for rendering. I doubt you can synchronise it's rendering, maybe you could limit the `FPS` or suspend layout on resize.